# how to play audio using variable file name?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

How to use a variable filename name, or How to pass the filename value while calling the media player.

Note: App is at API level 17.

```
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.music);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start playback.

                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())

                {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }

                mediaPlayer.start();
                }

            public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                return mediaPlayer;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a MediaPlayer object, you can reset it and set another data source. It is very useful to go through the media player states here (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#StateDiagram)

You can do the following in a method (when you want to switch):

```
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
//then continue with whatever you want to do
```